# className always empty

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I'm using [react-flexbox-grid](https://github.com/roylee0704/react-flexbox-grid)

Always I'm getting class Name empty so the layout doesn't work. any advice?. please ask me for further info is need, because I'm new with React I dont know which info share

[image: captura de pantalla de 2016-02-23 12-01-46]

I'm very curious because I have a simple component. I want the text *Hello from here* appear in the left and the form on right side

```
let layout = {
  xs: 6,
  sm: 6,
  md: 6,
  lg: 6
}


<Grid fluid>
  <Row>
    <Col {...layout}>
      <p>Hello from here</p>
    </Col>
    <Col {...layout}>
      <Paper>
        <Row>
          <TextField
            hintText='Name'
            floatingLabelText='Name'/>
        </Row>

        <Row>
          <TextField
            hintText='Email'
            floatingLabelText='Email'
            type='email'/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <TextField
            hintText='Password'
            floatingLabelText='Password'
            type='password'/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <TextField
            hintText='Re Enter Password'
            floatingLabelText='Re Enter Password'
            type='password'/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <a href='#'>Already have an account? Sign in</a>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <RaisedButton label='Submit' primary/>
        </Row>
      </Paper>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you forgotten to setup style-loader in your webpack config?

Comment: I don't know because I'm using webpack but the configuration was made but react starter redux kit

Comment: Could you please provide a style loader config example